# Getting probability values for random forest and Gradient Boosting in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, random-forest, gbm

I have been learning about classification techniques and studied about random forest, gradient boosting etc.Based on some help from codes available online,i tried to write code in python3 for random forest and GBM. My objective is to get the probability values from the model and not just look at accuracy as i intend to use the probability values to create KS later on.

I used the readily available titanic data set to start practicing.
Following are some of the steps i did :

```
/**load train data**/

train_df=pd.read_csv('***/classification/titanic/train.csv')

/**load test data**/

test_df =pd.read_csv('***/Desktop/classification/titanic/test.csv')

 /**drop some variables in train data**/

train_df = train_df.drop(['Ticket', 'Cabin'], axis=1)

 /**drop some variables in test data**/

test_df = test_df.drop(['Ticket', 'Cabin'], axis=1)

/** i calculated the title variable (again based on multiple threads in kaggle**/

train_df=pd.get_dummies(train_df,columns=['Pclass','Sex','Title'],drop_first=True)

test_df=pd.get_dummies(test_df,columns=['Pclass','Sex','Title'],drop_first=True)

/**i checked for missing and IV values next (not including that code here***/

predictors=[x for x in train.columns if x not in ['Survived','PassengerID']]

predictors

# create classifier object (GBM)

from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=10) 

# fit the classifier  with x and y data 

clf.fit(train[predictors],train.Survived)
prob=pd.DataFrame({'prob':clf.predict_proba(train[predictors])[:,1]})
prob['prob'].value_counts()

# create classifier object (RF)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=10) 

# fit the classifier  with x and y data 

clf.fit(train[predictors],train.Survived)
prob=pd.DataFrame({'prob':clf.predict_proba(train[predictors])[:,1]})
prob['prob'].value_counts()
```

Now when i check the probability values from the two different models, i noticed that for the Random forest output, a significant chunk had a 0 probability score whereas that was not the case for the GBM model.

I understand that the techniques are different, but how can the results be so far off ? Am i missing out on something ?

With a large chunk of the population getting tagged with '0' as probability score, my KS table goes for a toss.

Comment: Please use the correct format for comments in your Python code - prefixing lines with `/**` is *not* the way to do it.

Comment: Hi, these r comments which i wrote to make the code flow understandable for my question. Not something which i had present  in my actual code.

Comment: This does not change the fact that they are comments indeed, and since you have chosen to include them in your code in such a way, you should format them accordingly. If they were there or not in your original code is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! Since you don't seem to be having an issue with code execution in specific, or totally incorrect outputs, this looks like it is more appropriate for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), where you can find answers to questions of statistical concerns.

In fact, I'd suggest that answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) might give you some good insights into why you are seeing very different values from the `predict_proba` method. In short: while both `GradientBoostingClassifier` and `RandomForestClassifier` both use tree methods, what they do is very different, so direct comparison of the model parameters is not necessarily appropriate.